# JWT auth without UserDetails from DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, token

I'm trying to implement JWT authentication in Spring Security. But I don't understand how can I use it without UserDetails from DB, because I get users from remote LDAP server and don't store them in my DB.

How I can replace this fetching UserDetails for another one thing? Any ideas?

Here my JwtAuthenticationFilter class:

```
package com.kddb_webimporter.security;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.kddb_webimporter.models.User;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter  {

//    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

//    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, 
            JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider, 
            CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService ) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);
            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {

              UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("");
              /*How to replace it?*/

              UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                  userDetails, 
                  null, 
                  userDetails.getAuthorities()
              ); 

              authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

              SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a loot at the [LdapUserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetailsService.html)

Comment: @MatheusCirillo can you provide some code for this? I can't understand how to use it